# How to dynamically change filename while writing in a loop

Tags: c

I want to open file in 20 loop. Every time the name of the folder changes.Like This variables1,variables2,variables3......variables20 I found the same question in here , but it didnt help me.

Here's what I have tried:

```
 int l=1;
 while(l<20){                                                                            
    char filename[10];
    sprintf (filename, "variables%d", l);
                     OR
    scanf("%s", filename);                   

    FILE * fp; 
    if ((fp = fopen (filename,"rb")) == NULL){ 
    printf("Failed to Open File variables%d\n",l);}  
    ...........  Reading Data........
    fclose (fp);
    l++;
 }
```

I can wite Filename  succesfully but I got the error: `Failed to Open File variables1`

[SOLVED] I am just sodding idiot.Thank you for your concern and answers... i just forgot to add ".bin" sprintf (filename, "variables%d.bin", l);

Comment: Why the C++ tag - this looks like vanilla C ?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you are writing C code, a C++ answer probably won't work, if you are writing C++ code, then why are you not using `std::string` and `iostreams`?

Comment: `filename` is probably getting corrupted by other variables on the stack, because you're exceeding its bounds. You can check this by using a debugger or simply printing `filename` in the `printf` call (instead of re-creating it there).

Comment: i have already do that.i print it using printf , and it matches.
variables1.bin

Answer (score 1):

Your `filename` buffer is too short - "variables1" requires 10 characters plus a `'\0'` terminator, so you need at least 11 characters for this buffer, and more when the index is > 9, otherwise you will get a buffer overflow and undefined behaviour. Change:

```
     char filename[10];
```

to:

```
     char filename[PATH_MAX];  // PATH_MAX is defined in <limits.h>
```

---

Also: if, as your title suggests, you want to *write* to these files, then you need to change:

```
      if ((fp = fopen (filename,"rb")) == NULL){
```

to:

```
      if ((fp = fopen (filename,"wb")) == NULL){
```

Comment: The pseudo code does say ".... Reading Data ...."

Comment: Ah yes - the title says "writing" though...

Comment: Or `MAX_PATH` depending on OS/compiler.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: `MAX_PATH` is a Windows abomination - `PATH_MAX` is portable.

Comment: Suggest putting the buffer-overflow point first, because it is most likely the actual cause. Requesting read access vs. write access isn't the cause of the open failure.

Comment: yes i open with wrong title. I just want to read data only.
i also tried filename[50]; it doesnt matter.

Comment: @SadViolinMan: it may not *appear* to matter *right now*, but buffer overflows cause undefined behaviour, and you must always be aware of the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You never increment your counter.
I would also recommend you to use a for loop like this

```
for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Repeatedly `fopen`ing the same file is perfectly legal. While it is true that the OP needs to fix their loop, this is not the cause of the error they are experiencing.

Comment: i just forgot to write here. i have it in my code.
And doesnt mather. even for 1 loop it gives error.
This is not a loop problem..